# How to detect app server embedded or standalone?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Is it possible to detect if a `spring-boot` application is running on an  `embedded tomcat` or on a `standalone tomcat server`?

I want to create a `@Configuration` that only executes on a standalone server.
But I don't want to use`@Profile` for this because all profiles should as well be executable inside an embedded tomcat during dev.

The following does not work so far:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)
public class TomcatConfig {
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)
        @Bean
        public MyBean init() {
                  //this should not execute in embedded tomcat
        }
}

@Configuration
public class MainConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainConfig.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you can probably just check for `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)`

Comment: Oh that's nice!

Comment: Actually i changed my answer to `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` to be Tomcat specific. Try both I guess. @membersound

Comment: As I want to execute the configuration inside standalone tomcat only, I tried using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class)` both on classlevel and on `@Bean` level. But the bean is still created running in embedded dev environment. Maybe it's possible to delay the configuration after Tomcat Autoconfiguration? But I could not find any class in spring repository that sets up `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`...

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood @membersound. The inverse is @ConditionalOnMissingBean so the configuration will execute when the bean is NOT present. See updated answer. The above bean is created in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration`

Comment: See my edit above. I added `@AutoConfigureAfter(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)` but still the bean is created though using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`